# Microsoft GDI. BitBlt vs StretchDIBits

Tags: c, windows, graphics, gdi+, blit

Hi so I'm trying to write a basic software renderer using the Windows GDI API, but I'm unsure which blitting option to use.

**Option 1: Use StretchDIBits directly on a simple Device Independent Bitmap directly**

**Option 2: Use BitBlt along with SetDIBits**

Now, I understand that BitBlt is meant to be used with Device Dependent Bitmaps, in which case it would certainly never be slower than StretcthDIBits, since there isn't a translation phase; however, since I don't really want to have to deal with DDBs and am using SetDIBits anyway, which will according to MSDN

> set the pixels in a compatible bitmap (DDB) using the color data
>   found in the specified DIB.

Can I assume that the speed would be comparable, if not in favor of StretchDIBits?

I tried to do research before posting my question, but it is entirely possible that I misunderstood what I read, so I'd really appreciate someone explaining the distinction between these 2 functions in a slightly less archaic way than MSDN.

Thanks!

***EDIT: I am using a Src and Dest Buffer with the same size btw, so the actual stretch functionality is almost irrelevant; I just need a 1:1 blit.***

Comment: `BitBlt` and `StretchBlt` draw `HBITMAP` on device context. `SetDIBitsToDevice` and `StretchDIBits` draw bits directly to screen. `SetDIBits` setups up `HBITMAP` to specific bits.

Comment: well I understand that. I'm more asking from a performance point of view. It is certainly a lot easier to just use StretchDIBits is certainly a lot easier to use, but I'm more so wondering whether that ease of use comes with extra drawbacks. Can Windows optimize since presumably the DCs will be in Kernel Memory or something along those lines? I guess my question is why would I ever use BitBlt if they effectively do the same thing.

Comment: It's two different set of functions. `BitBlt` is for drawing memory dc on to screen. `SetDIBitsToDevice` is used when you have the raw pixels. You should ask about a specific task. All you have said is you are making *"a basic software renderer"* and you want to know which function is better. There is no answer to that.

Comment: sure. so I want to do all the rendering myself. I'll fill the bitmap with all the RGB data myself. I really only need to blit the raw RGB data to the screen, which makes it seem to me like I may as well just use the SetDIBItsToDevice family of functions. I guess my question is why would you ever use BitBlt unless you are writing the DDB data directly to a bitmap selected into a DC. It just seems like an extra layer of indirection. I hope that makes a little more sense.

Comment: I understand the distinction between the 2 from a functional sense, but given that I can use both methods to achieve this simple task, I was curious whether there was a reason to favor one over the other in terms of performance. like why would i ever deal with DCs and BitBlt instead of just allocating an array and using SetDIBitsToDevice. I'd really appreciate some examples or context on when I'd choose to do this. Right now it seems like that would work well if I am drawing the same Bitmap many times, because I would only need to perform the DIB to DDB translation once.

Comment: particularly I am curious about this excerpt from MSDN: 

"An application that simply needs to display a pre-existing DIB can use the 
SetDIBitsToDevice function. For example, a spreadsheet application can open 
existing charts and display them in a window by using the SetDIBitsToDevice 
function. To repeatedly redraw a bitmap in a window, however, the application 
should use the BitBlt function. For example, a multimedia application that combines 
animated graphics with sound would benefit from calling the BitBlt function because 
it executes faster than SetDIBitsToDevice."

Comment: @Blu342:  What part of the excerpt isn't clear?  (I was about to write an answer that essentially said the same thing.)

Comment: well maybe im misinterpreting but it sounds like it is saying that if you are displaying static data use a DIB, but if it is redrawing use BitBlt, but I feel like it makes more sense the other way around. It seems like if you are constantly redrawing you have to incur the DIB to DDB translation every time anyway, whereas if you draw static content you can translate it to a DDB once then just redraw that every time.